# Android Двойной SeekBar

Tags: java, android

Ребят как можно сделать двойной Seekbar?
Например вот такой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел этот скрин, но к сожалению ссылка оказалась битая на библиотеку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На русском языке действительно, быстро ничего не находится. Но на английском целых две темы имеются: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795773/android-seekbar-with-two-thumbs), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836534/how-to-make-double-seekbar-in-android).